# M-RET to open buffer in new frame in helm-mini?

Tags: key-bindings, helm, buffers, frames

Is it possible to add a key binding `M-RET` to `helm-mini` which would open the selected buffer in a new frame instead of in the current window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should already be available as `helm-buffer-switch-other-frame`, bound to `C-c C-o`. You can see available actions by hitting `TAB` while in a Helm buffer.

To bind `M-RET` to `helm-buffer-switch-other-frame`, add the binding to [`helm-buffer-map`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/v2.5.4/helm-buffers.el#L148):

```el
(define-key helm-buffer-map (kbd "M-RET") #'helm-buffer-switch-other-frame)
```